# node size in igraph with R

Tags: r, nodes, igraph

I have such matrix to build a directed graph (sociogram):

```
sc=as.matrix(sociogram)
head(sc)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id1I1.png)

then I build my graph according with the following code:

```
ig <- graph.adjacency(sc, mode="directed", weighted=T)
coords <- layout_(ig, in_circle())

plot(ig, frame=T,
     edge.arrow.size=.5, 
     vertex.label.color="black", 
     vertex.label.dist=1.5,
     vertex.size=7.5,
     layout = coords)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnzPN.png)

Is there a way to change nodes size according with the number of arrows entering the nodes themselves?

No idea how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `vertex.size = degree(ig, mode = "in")`. Something like this:

```
g <- sample_gnp(20, .15, directed = TRUE)
plot(g, vertex.label = "", vertex.size = degree(g, mode = "in") *3)
```